# Tomcat/Spring-boot does not pick up Apache proxy headers

Tags: spring, apache, tomcat

So I have a spring-boot application running on tomcat. Now I have a apache proxy for providing two-way SSL authentication. The application does not pick up apache set certificates after authentication. Proxy work fine, because other applications do pick up the headers.

```
<Location "/app/secure">
    SSLRequireSSL
    SSLVerifyClient optional
    SSLVerifyDepth 3
    SSLOptions +ExportCertData +StdEnvVars
</Location>

RequestHeader set SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN "%{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN}s" env=SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN
many header here...

ProxyPass /app http://mylocalip:8080
ProxyPassReverse /app http://mylocalip:8080
```

I have set

```
server.use-forward-headers=true
```

And I try to read headers as follows

```
@RequestMapping(value="/auth", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String auth(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String client = null;
        String verify = request.getHeader("SSL_CLIENT_VERIFY");
        String cert = request.getHeader("SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN")
        return cert;
    }
```

Post to '/auth' is called upon '/app/secure.html' body load.

**EDIT:**
Does not seem to be tomcat's problem. Switched it for jetty and the issue persists. So either spring-boot is not forwarding the headers or I'm requesting them wrong.

Comment: It's more likely a problem with your `httpd` configuration. I'm pretty sure you want to be using the environment variable `SSL_CLIENT_S_DN` and not `SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN`.

Comment: Problem was that tomcat does not parse https headers if it is running on http. Went on using jetty.

Comment: Tomcat certainly does parse HTTP headers, regardless of any reverse proxy out in front of it. If you have a reference suggesting that Tomcat does not parse HTTP headers, please post it.